# Generate all n-bit numbers where the i-th bit is 0

Tags: c, numbers, bit-manipulation

I need to generate all `2^(n-1)` `n`-bit numbers where bit `i` is always `0` and `j` is the index of the number in the theoretical list of possible numbers, in ascending order. Here is a simple table for when `i` varies from 0 to 2 and `n` is 3, so `j` varies from 0 to 3. The result is a 3 bit number so `n` would be 3 and the number of possible numbers would be 4.

```
j   0 1 2 3
i
0   0 2 4 6
1   0 1 4 5
2   0 1 2 3
```

Or in binary:

```
j    00  01  10  11
i
00  000 010 100 110 // The 1s place bit is not set in this line
01  000 001 100 101 // Ditto the 2s place bit
10  000 001 010 011 // Ditto the 4s place bit
```

This is the best I could come up with, other than simply hardcoding all the possibilities:

```
unsigned result = (j&1)<<(i==0)|(j&2)<<(i!=2);
```

However, individually checking `i` with comparisons does not scale, and only works for the aforementioned table, and not for arbitrary values of `n` or `i`.

Can anyone think of a more generalized, more efficient way to generate all, specifically, the `j`-th smallest `n`-bit number where the `i`-th bit is 0?

Comment: OT: "_the LSB (1s place) bit_" "LSB" is good and understood. FYI, you can refer to bits as "... `b3`, `b2`, `b1`, `b0`" naming/numbering bits left-to-right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `j >> i << i` to clear the low `i` bits and add it to `j` to double the high bits, effectively shifting them left one bit:

`t = j + (j >> i << i);`

Comment: A similar one-liner: `t = j + (j & (~0u << i));`. (Change `0u` to another unsigned type 0 if necessary, e.g. `t = j + (j & (~(typeof(j))0 << i));`.)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a classic way to generate those numbers:

```
// make mask of the bits that can change
uint32_t mask = setNlowestBits(n) & ~(UINT32_C(1) << i);
uint32_t x = 0;
do {
    // use x
    ...
    // masked increment
    x = (x - mask) & mask;
} while (x != 0);
```

Implement `setNlowestBits` however you want, there are various implementation on the internet.

`mask` has a 1 at every bit that is allowed to change, `x - mask` is like subtracting -1 from an integer but with some "holes". Any borrows propagate  through the "holes" since the "holes" have zeroes in them. Then `& mask` resets any bits in the "holes" that became set by a borrow passing through it. In this case there is only one hole, but this technique also works with more holes.

Using modern instruction of the x86 platform, you can directly transform `j` into the desired number in a single step:

```
_pdep_u32(j, mask)
```

Where `mask` is either the same as before, or just `~(UINT32_C(1) << i)` if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You ask for something "more simple" than something that doesn't work. To me it seems better to start out getting something that actually works. Once you have that, you can look for improvements and optimizations.

For what it's worth here is a function that should work (boundary checks omitted for simplicity):

```
unsigned f(unsigned j, unsigned i)
{
    unsigned mlow = (1 << i) - 1;
    unsigned mhigh = ~mlow << 1;
    return (2*j & mhigh) | (j & mlow);
}
```

To see it in action:

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned bits = 5;
    unsigned combs = 1 << (bits - 1);
    
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < bits; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < combs; ++j)
        {
            printf("%2u ", f(j, i));
        }
        puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 
 0  1  4  5  8  9 12 13 16 17 20 21 24 25 28 29 
 0  1  2  3  8  9 10 11 16 17 18 19 24 25 26 27 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```